# Help needed for adding and edit & delete link in a column in a view table

Tags: views

I need to implement views with a table format to display fields for selected content.  I would like one of the columns to have edit/delete links that will request perform the desired task for the row selected.  I have seen it done on sites, but have not found an example In which to review the view configuration.

Clarification:  Each row in a table represents a content node and each column would display a field in the content type.  I want to put an edit link that will call up the specific node in that row in the editing form.

Comment: By default you can find edit and delete link for any content type in view just add new field and search for edit and delete,or you ask about something else

Comment: Ahmed, your comment is not clear. What do you mean by "search for edit and delete"?

Comment: edit and delete field in view (you can search for fields)

Answer (score 3):

Could you just add a field with the node ID and rewrite it to reconstruct the url, inserting the node id where applicable (different structures for different entity types)?

Comment: I could if there were only one option, but I have seen views displays with both links in the same table cell.

Comment: You can add another nid field and use the table settings to combine the two columns into one, with a custom separator for the links. That's how most views do it

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for that which could help you: the [editablefields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) module.

> This module allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g. at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). It also works within the Views module, etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected, you can select editable (or click to edit).
>
> This module has been totally re-written for Drupal 6, and it is very much simpler.