# custom table view: delete/edit row D7

Tags: 7

I've spent hours trying to find good examples or working scripts, but couldn't find anything yet. What I *desire* to achieve: I have a sortable table with database entries in it, each row has a edit and delete link with each its own ID. So far so good. Now I have to add the functionality to actually delete/edit DB rows. Im totally lost..

Its a custom module and don't want to use other modules to achieve this, so these answers are useless : [Help needed for adding and edit & delete link in a column in a view table](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34011/help-needed-for-adding-and-edit-delete-link-in-a-column-in-a-view-table)

[I also found this website](http://public-action.org/content/drupal-7-form-api-modify-and-delete-record-operations-drupal-7-multi-step-form-fapi)

but the description is way too complicated and I think the whole script is incomplete.

I've also tried the http://drupal.org/project/examples but that didn't get me any further

does anyone have really good examples or a complete working module?

thanks for your input

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Are you asking only how to delete from the DB?

Comment: yes, when I click on 'delete' the row should be deleted from the DB. So im looking for that whole logic/system

Comment: do you know how to use `hook_menu()`?

Comment: yes, but it gets more complicated than that, been searching through so many other modules, websites etc.. I really need a simple working example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all you want a page callback to handle the deleting. You either want to use [`confirm_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/confirm_form/7) or add a token to the link to avoid CSRF. node.module does the former, so I'd go with core. You can also use that as a reference: [`node_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_menu/7) (look for `$items['node/%node/delete']`), [`node_delete_confirm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.pages.inc/function/node_delete_confirm/7), [`node_delete_confirm_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_delete_confirm_submit/7).

Regarding the actual deleting, [this page](http://drupal.org/node/310081) has some instructions. Please update the Q if you have specific issues.

Here's an example, not tested:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['MYMODULE/%/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Delete',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('MYMODULE_delete_confirm', 1),
    'access arguments' => array('PERMISSION_TO_CHECK'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Form function returning a delete thingy confirmation form.
 */
function MYMODULE_delete_confirm($form, &$form_state, $id) {
  $form['#MYMODULE']['id'] = $id;

  $name = MYMODULE_get_name_from_id($id);

  return confirm_form($form,
    t("Are you sure you want to delete %name?", array('%name' => $name)),
    '<front>',
    t("This action cannot be undone."),
    t("Delete"),
    t("Cancel")
  );
}

/**
 * Submit handler for MYMODULE_delete_confirm.
 */
function MYMODULE_delete_confirm_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form['#MYMODULE']['id'])) {
    $id = $form['#MYMODULE']['id'];
    db_delete('MYMODULE_thingy')
      ->condition('id', $id)
      ->execute();
  }
}

/**
 * Loads the name of the thingy from its id.
 */
function MYMODULE_get_name_from_id($id) {
  return 'thingy ' . $id;
}
```

Comment: kk thanks i'll continue trying, can't believe something so simple is so hard to achieve in drupal :(

Comment: I'm not sure why this is proving so difficult: can you clarify exactly what's causing the problem?

Comment: Well, it's all so confusing. Im used to stand alone php, compared to drupal, normal php is childish..With drupal I need simple and logic examples. But thanks for your time andy :) If you do have a good working example, please provide

Comment: Yeah it can take time to get your head around how things are done. You've specifically asked how to do this without helper modules - it's quite possible that you can do everything you want to with no custom coding at all.

Comment: @mhmdrupal have added example, HTH

Comment: yeah I know, of course there are a lot of great modules, but this is a very important practice for me. Im determined to become a skilled Drupal developer :) Thanks for the example Andy, and again thanks a lot for your help. Will post on success :)

Comment: one last thing: how do I trigger the first step (confirmation)? This is the current delete link: <a id='delete' href='#'>" . t('Delete') . "</a>  You can get the ID with: $node->id

Comment: To delete item 42 go to `MYMODULE/42/delete`. For more info look at [the docs for `hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

Comment: thanks for all your help Andy! Got it! :) Really appreciate it

Comment: Some additional helpful information regarding this topic: how to create a edit and delete function in a custom module - https://www.drupal.org/node/2069383 and Wildcard Loader Arguments - https://www.drupal.org/node/224170

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
// $Id$
/**
* @file
* First menu module file
* Learning Menu
*/
/**
* Implement hook_help().
*/
function learning_help($path, $arg) {
  if ($path == 'admin/help#learning') {
    return t('learning menu.');
  }
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function learning_menu() {
  $menuitems['hello'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hello world',
    'page callback' => 'sam_mymenu',
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );    
  $menuitems['survey'] = array(
    'title' => t('Survey form'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('survey_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  $menuitems['admin/people/survey'] = array(
    'title' => t('Survey List'),
    'page callback' => 'survey_list',
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $menuitems['admin/people/survey/%/delete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Delete Survey item',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('delete_survey_record_comfirm',3),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  ); 
  $menuitems['admin/people/survey/%/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit Survey item',
    'page callback' => 'form_values_edit',
    'page arguments' => array(3),
    'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );  
  return $menuitems;
}

/**
 * Display Hello World.
 */
function sam_mymenu() {
  return t('Hello world');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function learning_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['show_ip'] = array(
    'info' => t('Show IP Address.'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );
  $blocks['recent_survey'] = array(
    'info' => t('Recent Survey'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function learning_block_view($block_name = '') {
  if ($block_name == 'show_ip') {
    $list = ip_address();
    $content = $list;
    $block = array(
      'subject' => t('Current IP Address'),
      'content' => $content,
    );
  }
  if ($block_name == 'recent_survey') {
    $query = db_select('learning', 'n')
      ->fields('n')
      ->orderBy('sid', 'DESC')
      ->range(0,3)
      ->execute();
    $list = array();
    while($data = $query->fetchAssoc()){
      $list[] = $data;
    }
    $count = count($list);
    $content = "<table border='0'>
      <tr>
        <th>" . t('Name') ."</th>
        <th>" . t('Email') ."</th>
      </tr>";    
    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
      $content .= "<tr><td>". $list[$i]['name'] . "</td>";
      $content .= "<td>". $list[$i]['email'] . "</td></tr>";
    }

    $content .= "</table>";
    $block = array(
      'subject' => t('Recent Survey'),
      'content' => $content,
    );
  }
    return $block;
}

/**
 * Implements survey_form().
 */
function survey_form($form, &$form_state, $my_object) {

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#required' => TRUE, 
    '#default_value' => isset($my_object['name']) ? $my_object['name'] : '',
  );
  $form['sid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $my_object['sid'],
  );

  $form['email'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Email'),
    '#required' => TRUE, 
    '#default_value' => isset($my_object['email']) ? $my_object['email'] : '',
  );  
  $form['age'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Age'),
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(range(18, 100)),
    '#default_value' => isset($my_object['age']) ? $my_object['age'] : '',
  );       
  $form['gender'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Gender'),
    '#options' => array(
      'male' => t('male'), 
      'female' => t('female')
    ),
    '#default_value' => isset($my_object['gender']) ? $my_object['gender'] : '',
  );    
  $form['about'] = array(
    '#title' => t('About'),
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#cols' => 60,
    '#rows' => 5,
    '#default_value' => isset($my_object['about']) ? $my_object['about'] : '',
  );
  $form['disclaimer'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('disclaimer', FALSE),
    '#title' => t('I agree that the information provided above are true to my knowledge'),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Send Surveys'),
  );
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements From Validation.
 */
function survey_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {

  if (!valid_email_address($form_state['values']['email'])) {
    form_set_error('email', t('That e-mail address is not valid.'));
  }
  if (!($form_state['values']['disclaimer'])) {
    form_set_error('disclaimer', t('Please accept our legal to proceed.'));
  }
  $words = explode(' ',$form_state['values']['about']);
  $count_words = count($words);
  if ($count_words < 50) {
    form_set_error('about', t('About should have at least 50 words.'));
  }
}

/**
 * Implements survey_form_submit().
 */
function survey_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {  
  if(isset($form_state['values']['sid'])) {
    db_update('learning')
      ->fields(array(
        'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
        'email' => $form_state['values']['email'],
        'age' => $form_state['values']['age'],
        'gender' => $form_state['values']['gender'],
        'about' => $form_state['values']['about'], 
      ))
      ->condition('sid', $form_state['values']['sid'] )
      ->execute();
    drupal_set_message(t('Record has been updated.'));    
  }
  else {
  // Here u can insert Your custom form values into your custom table.
    db_insert('learning')
      ->fields(array(
        'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
        'email' => $form_state['values']['email'],
        'age' => $form_state['values']['age'],
        'gender' => $form_state['values']['gender'],
        'about' => $form_state['values']['about'],      
      ))->execute();
    drupal_set_message("successfully saved survey details.");    
  }
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'admin/people/survey';
}

/**
 * Display Suryvey form list.
 */
function survey_list(){
  //return t('Survey List');
  $query = db_select('learning', 'n')
    ->fields('n')
    ->execute();
  $rows = array();
  while($data = $query->fetchAssoc()){
      // Fill the table rows
    $data['operation'] = l(t('Delete'), 'admin/people/survey/' . $data['sid'] . '/delete');
    $data['operation'] .= "|";
    $data['operation'] .= l(t('Edit'), 'admin/people/survey/' . $data['sid'] . '/edit');
    $rows[] = array('data' => $data, 'style' => 'word-break:break-all;',);
  }

  // Prepare table header
  $header = array( t('S.No'),t('Name'), t('Email'), t('Age'), t('Gender'), t('About'),t('operation'));
  // Output of table with the paging
  $output = theme_table(
    array(
      "header" => $header,
      "rows" => $rows,
      "attributes" => array(),
      "sticky" => true, // Table header will be sticky
      "caption" => "",
      "colgroups" => array(),
      "empty" => t("Table has no row!") // The message to be displayed if table is empty
    )
  );
  return $output;
}

/**
 * Delete Survey Record Confirmation
 */
function delete_survey_record_comfirm($form, &$form_state, $id){
  //die($id);
  $form['delete'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => $id,
  );
  return confirm_form(
    $form,
    t('Are you sure you want to delete this?'),
    'admin/people/survey',
    t('This action cannot be undone.'),
    t('Delete'),
    t('Cancel')
  );
}

/**
 * Delete Survey Record Function
 */
function delete_survey_record_comfirm_submit($form, &$form_state) { 
  $record = $form_state['values']['delete'];
  if ($record ) {
    $num_deleted = db_delete('learning')
      ->condition('sid', $record )
      ->execute();
    drupal_set_message('The record has been deleted!');
  }
  $form_state['redirect'] = "admin/people/survey";
}

/**
 * form_values_edit
 */
function form_values_edit($id){
  $id_val = $id;
  $my_object = db_select('learning', 'n')
    ->fields('n')
    ->condition('sid', $id_val )
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();
  return drupal_get_form('survey_form', $my_object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Create menu for Delete 



    $menuitems['admin/people/survey/%/edit'] = array( 
        'title' => 'Edit Survey item', 
        'page callback' => 'form_values_edit', 
        'page arguments' => array(3), 
        'access arguments' => array('administer users'), 
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
      ); 





    /** 
    * Delete Survey Record Confirmation 
    */ 
    function delete_survey_record_comfirm($form, &$form_state, $id){ 
      //die($id); 
      $form['delete'] = array( 
        '#type' => 'value', 
        '#value' => $id, 
      ); 
      return confirm_form( 
        $form, 
        t('Are you sure you want to delete this?'), 
        'admin/people/survey', 
        t('This action cannot be undone.'), 
        t('Delete'), 
        t('Cancel') 
      ); 
    } 

    /** 
    * Delete Survey Record Function 
    */ 
    function delete_survey_record_comfirm_submit($form, &$form_state) {  
      $record = $form_state['values']['delete']; 
      if ($record ) { 
        $num_deleted = db_delete('learning') 
          ->condition('sid', $record ) 
          ->execute(); 
        drupal_set_message('The record has been deleted!'); 
      } 
      $form_state['redirect'] = "admin/people/survey"; 
    }
```